# Symfony 1.4x and sfTCPDFPlugin

Tags: plugins, symfony1, tcpdf

I have installed sfTCPDFPlugin in my project, but when I try to test if the installation is alright (with the source found on the official site) I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in C:\wamp\www\mairie\plugins\sfTCPDFPlugin\lib\sfTCPDF.class.php  on line 12
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The done thing around these parts is to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the readme tab here : http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin
It says you have to download the tcpdf library, not only the sfTCPDFPlugin.

Answer (score 0):

i faced with same problem, and i did the following task it will also help you.
first of all run:    `symfony plugin:uninstall sfTCPDFPlugin` then remove the sfTCPDFPlugin directory form your plugin folder.
mow do the following setps:
1. `cd your project path/symfony`
2. `symfony plugin:install sfTCPDFPlugin`
3. download the tcpdf library unzip it and past into your sfTCPDFPlugin/lib now your directory looks like your project path/symfony/plugins/sfTCPDFPlugin/lib/tcpdf
now change your ProjectConfiguration.class.php to add `$this->enablePlugins( array('sfTCPDFPlugin') );` now run the `symfony plugin:publish-asstes` and finally clear the cache `symfony cc`.